# Can Seam 2.0.2sp1 apps run on Tomcat 5.5.9 with JBoss Embedded?

Tags: java, jpa, seam

I'm trying to run the Tomcat with JBoss Embedded jpa booking example.  I run the build and deploy the war.  I then get the following error:

```
ERROR [catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/jboss-seam-jpa]] Error configuring application listener of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/CompositeELResolver
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2357)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2671)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:321)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3618)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4104
```

I find this class exists in el-api.jar which is not in the classpath.  So I add el-api.jar to the WEB-INF/lib directory.  I then get the following error:

```
INFO: JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy annotations present.  ManagedBeans methods marked with these annotations will have said annotations processed.
Sep 19, 2008 5:37:50 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener installExpressionFactory
SEVERE: Error Instantiating ExpressionFactory
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1332)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1181)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:164)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.installExpressionFactory(ConfigureListener.java:1521)
```

This library appears to be in el-ri.jar or JSP 2.1 jar.  Am I doing something wrong?  Is there a place that explains how to run seam applications on tomcat 5.5.x?  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work.  I ran ant tomcat55 under the seam/examples/jpa example.  This included the el-*.jars needed.  I then ran 'ant clean' and 'ant jboss-embeded' and manually copied in all of the el-*.jars from the tomcat55 make.  This got past my problem above.  Now I'm able to start tomcat 5.5.9 with embedded JBoss.  I can run the booking example now with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at the docs, there's also some pretty good info on the forums at www.seamframework.org and also the old forums at www.jboss.org.

Comment: Thanks!  I did post on the seamframework.org user forum.  I was just curious if stackoverflow.com community would be able to come up with an answer for such a specific question.